# How to handle non-json response while using jquery $.post?

Tags: jquery, json

I am using the standard pattern `$.post(url,function(d){ alert(d.msg); },'JSON');` to receive response from the server, the server sends the response as text/html but is normally a formatted json string so this code works well, but there is a chance that the server may send a malformed json string or plain text or html, how can I modify the code to respond to that situation as well?

Comment: get the repsonse as text, and then convert it to json. if the conversion was not success, on client side, then do something if it is, then do another thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking the content-type

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your url goes here", 
  data: "data to be sent", 
  success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
    var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
    if (ct.indexOf('html') > -1) {
      //do something
    }
    if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
      // handle json here
    } 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an error handler.

Since you have defined the dataType as `'json'`, if the data returned is invalid json , jquery will trigger the error callback.
It will also be triggered for other possible ajax errors as well so you should always use an error handler anyway

```
$.post(url,function(d){ 
    alert(d.msg); 
},'json').error(function(xhr, errorThrown){
    alert('Error thrown = ' + errorThrown);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/QeH2jjGX7Dr9pKblXBqO?p=preview)**</kbd>